# bootstrap table ajax not loading styles

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have a bootstrap table in my page and I'm getting some data via ajax to make some rows. However when data is parsed form ajax the table doesn't have any styles to it. But when I paste the same html code from ajax, in my php file and load it on the browser it shows just fine. Here is the js function but there is no error to it. I'm apparently missing something about bootstrap loading dynamic content?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    new request('records', {
        column: 'id',
        order: 'DESC'
    }, processReply);
});

function processReply(data) {

    this.createRow = function () {
        return document.createElement('tr');
    }

    this.createCell = function () {
        return document.createElement('td');
    }


    this.container = document.getElementById('records-table')

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var tr = this.createRow();

        for (prop in data[i]) {

            var td = this.createCell();
            td.innerHTML = data[i][prop];
            tr.appendChild(td);

        }

        container.appendChild(tr);
    }

}

function request(cmd, args, callback) {

    var req = $.ajax({
        url: "/api/" + cmd,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            params: args
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });

    req.done(function (reply) {
        callback(reply);
    });

    req.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        //alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });

    req.always(function () {
        console.log('Ajax complete!');
    });
}
```

Here is the complete html after the ajax is complete:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="records table-responsive">
    <table id="records-table" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover tablesorter">

      <tr>
        <td>
          10
        </td>
        <td>
          2013-12-26 10:45:27
        </td>
        <td>
          KIO-6729
        </td>
        <td>
          Giannis
        </td>
        <td>
          Papafilis
        </td>
        <td>
          Giwrgos
        </td>
        <td>
          Thewdorou
        </td>
        <td>
          20
        </td>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          16
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          Varkiza
        </td>
        <td>
          Glyfada
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          9
        </td>
        <td>
          2013-10-06 08:32:52
        </td>
        <td>
          KIO-6729
        </td>
        <td>
          Giannis
        </td>
        <td>
          Papafilis
        </td>
        <td>
          Maria
        </td>
        <td>
          Papadopoulou
        </td>
        <td>
          8
        </td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          7
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          P.Falliro
        </td>
        <td>
          Voula
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          6
        </td>
        <td>
          2013-10-08 21:35:23
        </td>
        <td>
          KIO-6729
        </td>
        <td>
          Lefteris
        </td>
        <td>
          Xourmouzis
        </td>
        <td>
          Maria
        </td>
        <td>
          Papadopoulou
        </td>
        <td>
          40
        </td>
        <td>
          5
        </td>
        <td>
          30
        </td>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          Mesogeiwn
        </td>
        <td>
          Rafina
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          5
        </td>
        <td>
          2013-10-10 15:19:45
        </td>
        <td>
          KIO-6729
        </td>
        <td>
          Lefteris
        </td>
        <td>
          Xourmouzis
        </td>
        <td>
          Giwrgos
        </td>
        <td>
          Thewdorou
        </td>
        <td>
          15
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          13
        </td>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          Gkazi
        </td>
        <td>
          Ilioupoli
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          2013-10-08 14:26:47
        </td>
        <td>
          YOE-1284
        </td>
        <td>
          Tasos
        </td>
        <td>
          Papadopoulos
        </td>
        <td>
          Giwrgos
        </td>
        <td>
          Thewdorou
        </td>
        <td>
          20
        </td>
        <td>
          5
        </td>
        <td>
          15
        </td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
        <td>
          Peristeri
        </td>
        <td>
          Gkizi
        </td>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
        <td>
          2013-10-08 07:49:22
        </td>
        <td>
          XYZ-9870
        </td>
        <td>
          Giannis
        </td>
        <td>
          Papafilis
        </td>
        <td>
          Alexia
        </td>
        <td>
          Manda
        </td>
        <td>
          20
        </td>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
        <td>
          17
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          Peiraias
        </td>
        <td>
          Athina kedro
        </td>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          2013-10-02 09:47:26
        </td>
        <td>
          EYX-3464
        </td>
        <td>
          Giannis
        </td>
        <td>
          Papafilis
        </td>
        <td>
          Maria
        </td>
        <td>
          Papadopoulou
        </td>
        <td>
          40
        </td>
        <td>
          5
        </td>
        <td>
          35
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          kalamaki
        </td>
        <td>
          glyfada
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          2013-10-16 18:26:43
        </td>
        <td>
          EYX-3464
        </td>
        <td>
          Tasos
        </td>
        <td>
          Papadopoulos
        </td>
        <td>
          Giwrgos
        </td>
        <td>
          Thewdorou
        </td>
        <td>
          50.9
        </td>
        <td>
          20.9
        </td>
        <td>
          30
        </td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          braxami
        </td>
        <td>
          megalo peuko
        </td>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Changing the code and using innerHTML instead of createElement seems to solve the issue and the ajax loaded table renders ok with all the bootstrap styles. However I don't know this doesn't happen with createELement.

Comment: Why do you give a `new` keyword there?

Comment: that are some parameters for the ajax request for my php api. requests records and what column to sort it and what type of order

Comment: would have less code and not run into this problem if simply used jQuery insertion methods since you are already using jQuery